# How can i disable the standard tab event in the tinymce editor?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

is there a solution to disable the standard tab event?

If the user press the tab key, I want to insert 8 spaces.
But if I press the tab key, he jump to the next button.
And if the focus return to the Editor he insert the spaces.

the code:

```
tinymce.init({
...
setup: function (editor) {
                //Tastenkombinationen
                editor.on('keyup', function (e, evt) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
                        editor.insertContent('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')
                    }
});
...
});
```

I want to insert the spaces instantly, without jumping to the buttons.

thanks for help :)

Comment: Have a look into this blog post: http://www.wexoo.net/20130412/map-tab-key-to-indent-and-shifttab-to-outdent-in-tinymce-in-wicket

Comment: The mistake was the key event. I used "keyup" but I need "keydown" and then it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tinymce.init({
...
setup: function (editor) {
                //Tastenkombinationen
                editor.on('keydown', function (e, evt) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
                        e.preventDefault();
editor.insertContent('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')
                        }
    });
    ...
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe `e.preventDefault()` is what you need. It stops the default action of an element from happening.

```
if (e.keyCode == 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    editor.insertContent('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is what I mean.
But I need a "keydown" event and not "keyup", because the standard tab event works on "keydown".